# vtrace / vivisect resources

Tags: python, dynamic-analysis, static-analysis

Where can I find some resources to start learning about vivisect? 
Blog posts, presentations, PDFs, code examples, anything would be appreciated.

I am aware I can read the code but before doing that I would like to have something to get me started.

Comment: Mandiant had a decent blog post on it a while back. https://www.mandiant.com/blog/custom-vdb-debugger-exploit-analysis/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a nice blog entry on it here: http://www.singlehop.com/blog/binary-vivisection-part-1/

> ...
>
> While looking over the changelog and documentation, I realized that
>   there doesn’t really seem to be a good tutorial or primer for getting
>   familiar with the **Vivisect** framework so hopefully we can remediate
>   that today.  In this series, we’ll be covering the usage of VDB
>   (dynamic debugging component) and **vivisect** (static analysis tool).
>
> ...

You can also see the `README` file [here](https://code.google.com/p/vtrace-mirror/source/browse/trunk/README-vivisect), and some related scripts [here](https://github.com/pdasilva/vtrace_scripts).